# Colocando um form-inline dentro de uma panel-group e continuar todos elementos in-line

Tags: css3, bootstrap-3

Não estou conseguindo alinhar o "Collapsible Group Item #1" com os "form(s)" como pode ser visto neste exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/mzygnyb2/

Busquei colocar a classe 'in-line' em algumas partes do código esperando alinhar, mas não está funcionando. Somebody save me? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer deixar alinhado o h4 ele tem que estar dentro do form e com a classe form-inline tambem.

Exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/mzygnyb2/1/

Comment: A entendi, eu tinha colocado em panel, por isso não funcionava, muito obrigado Diogenes o/